# Unity Newtonsoft JSON Android Build MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'System.ComponentModel.ReferenceConverter' not found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net

I got stuck with exception when Deserialize object with Newtonsoft JSON. In Unity editor it work as expected, but on android build it failed with "MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'System.ComponentModel.ReferenceConverter' not found." error.
I Use IL2CPP build and API Compatibility standart .NET Standart 2.0

Example of deserializing code:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IpLocationData>(ipLocationString);
```

IpLocationData:

```
public class IpLocationData : IIpLocationData
{
    public IpLocationData(ConnectionData connection, CurrencyData currency, LocationData location, bool success, TimeData time)
    {
        ConnectionData = connection;
        CurrencyData = currency;
        LocationData = location;
        Success = success;
        TimeData = time;
    }

    [JsonProperty("connection")]
    public IConnectionData ConnectionData { get; }
    [JsonProperty("currency")]
    public ICurrencyData CurrencyData { get; }
    [JsonProperty("location")]
    public ILocationData LocationData { get; }
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; }
    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public ITimeData TimeData { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have a parameterless constructor `public IpLocationData(){ }` and try again ... might have your properties to be assignable though .. is there a special reason anyway why you use interfaces if in the constructor you get the actual types anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

You have to put file named `link.xml` in your `Assets` folder and put here code below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="System">
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.ReferenceConverter">
            <method signature="System.Void .ctor(System.Type)" />
        </type>
    </assembly>
</linker>
```